# Library for windows color picker

Tags: windows, library, java

Is there a library that has the Windows color picker you see in ms paint and the desktop wallpaper setting dialog and elsewhere? The tiny file dialogs that comes with lwjgl3 (lightweight java game library) doesn't support getting or setting the user defined colors. I've tried using the Windows forms one with jni4net, but can't get the example to run. Here's the Stackoverflow question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083930/jni4net-example-in-visual-studio-community-2019-fails-to-build-despite-targeting It needs to be able to get and set the user defined colors.

Comment: Which Paint do you mean? The new store app (Metro) or the classic one? There's at least the [color picker dialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/color-dialog-box) ...

Answer (score 2):

MS Paint and similar are probably using the common dialog controls that Microsoft provides.

Probably won't be able to use the Windows one, but GTK, Qt, and WxWidgets all have some level of support or wrapper to be used from Java, and one or more of them should have a color picker dialog available.

Answer (score 1):

Since it about Java, what about JColorChooser?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/61571)

Comment: He asked about color picker and JColorChooser could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A time ago I developed the small library [UiBooster](https://github.com/Milchreis/UiBooster). With it you can create a picker very easy. It is not the Paint color picker, but similar.

[image]

```
Color selectedColor = new UiBooster().showColorPicker("Choose your favorite color", "Color picking");
```